# How to I get user role data in controller and displaying laravel

Tags: laravel, user-roles

How do I display by dropdown in view page?

**User model:**

```
public function registrationRoles(){
    return [
       3=>'Teacher',
       4=>'Student'
    ];
}
```

**My view page**

```
<select class="select" name="role_id" id="all-categories">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="">Teacher</option>
    <option value="">Student</option>
</select>
```

**RegisterController**

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name'    => 'required',
            'last_name'     => 'required',
            'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone'         => 'required|numeric',
            'password'      => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

    $data = new User;
    $data->first_name    = $request->first_name;
    $data->last_name     = $request->last_name;
    $data->email         = $request->email;
    $data->phone         = $request->phone;
    $data->password      = bcrypt($request->password);
    // $data->role_id       = 0;
    $data->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Waiting for admin approval');
    return redirect('/register');
}
```

..............................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using blade:-

You can find the necessary readings here https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists

```
{!! Form::select('role_id', <here you have to place returned value from registrationRoles>) !!}
```

Comment: laravel 4.2 hasn't been supported in years, html/form builder isn't even part of laravel any more, the OP is using at least 5.0

Answer (score 0):

You could start by hardcoding them in the html

```
<select class="select" name="role_id" id="all-categories">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="0">Teacher</option>
    <option value="1">Student</option>
</select>
```

In your controller

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name'    => 'required',
            'last_name'     => 'required',
            'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone'         => 'required|numeric',
            'password'      => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

    $data = new User;
    $data->first_name    = $request->first_name;
    $data->last_name     = $request->last_name;
    $data->email         = $request->email;
    $data->phone         = $request->phone;
    $data->password      = bcrypt($request->password);
    $data->role_id       = $request->role_id;
    $data->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Waiting for admin approval');
    return redirect('/register');
}
```

Or you could populate the dropdown with the roles if your return the roles in the view
like

```
$roles = Roles::all();
return view('yourView', compact('roles));
```

In your blade

```
<select class="select" name="role_id" id="all-categories">
    @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```